# Is $f(m,n)=2^m\cdot(2n+1)$ a bijection between $\Bbb{Z_{\geq0}\times Z\to Z}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification

> Let $\mathbb Z$  denote the set of integers and $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$
>   denote the set $\{0,1,2,3,...\}$. Consider the map $f:\mathbb Z_{\ge
>  0}\times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ given by $f(m,n)=2^m\cdot(2n+1)$. Then
>   the map $f$ is
>
> (A)injective but not surjective.
>
> (B)surjective but not injective.
>
> (C)injective and surjective.
>
> (D)neither injective nor surjective.

**For injectivity,**

$$2^{m_1-m_2}(2n_1+1)=(1)(2n_2+1)$$
$$2^{m_1-m_2}(2n_1+1)=2^0(2n_2+1)$$ 
$$m_1=m_2 \land n_1=n_2   $$

**For surjectivity,**
$m=0$, $f$ maps to odd integers.Similarly, I am getting pre-image for even integers also.

So, (C) is the correct answer. Am I correct? But, solution manual gives (A) as the correct one. Who is correct? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(m,n) = 2^m\cdot(2n+1)$ can never be zero, since neither factor can be zero. Therefore the mapping is not surjective.

Comment: I really forget about $0$. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that $0$ is not mapped by any pair of $(m,n)$ (as $2^m \geq 1$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$). So, $\implies \, ?$

Comment: Your answer is basically the same as mine, and you entered it a few seconds before I entered mine, so I upvoted your answer.